# The type name 'EmployeeReference' does not exist in the type 'HRMS'

Tags: c#

I am facing an issue where I am trying to build my project file in Microsoft Visual Studio, but I am being shown this error:

```
The type name 'EmployeeReference' does not exist in the type 'HRMS'
```

This error is popping up from the Reference.cs file. Can I know how to fix this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's hard to tell what's wrong about everything related with project stuff without seeing all this stuff, because too much things might be the reason.

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo what are the main details its required? I can provide it.

Comment: probably you need to start with sharing the version of VS, project file and `Reference.cs`

Comment: To elaborate -- you probably know all about the type `HRMS` and the type name `EmployeeReference`, but other users at StackOverflow in all probability know nothing about them.